# How to properly require a node module, exporting all the functions in it

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a file stats.js.

It's contents are

```
(function () {
    func1 = function () {

    }
    func2 = function () {

    }

    module.exports = this;

}).call(this);
```

Alegedly, when I do

```
var stats = require("./stats");
```

I should be able to get func1 and func2 with stats.func1, stats.func2, right?

Well, I can't. The stats object is just empty. A few traces in the stats.js revealed that "this" is also an empty object.

What gives?

Comment: Are you on purpose trying to assign the functions to the global object and then trying to export the global object?

Comment: I don't think I want that. I want the function to be accessible by requiring the file and then doing stats.func.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it shouldnt? That format is nothing like what Node.js needs in order to do its job.

"What gives" is that you didn't read up on how node works. Node.js isn't just "JavaScript", it's a proramming model with a much richer API and specific behaviours. Requires use the "module.exports" object, so it would be a good idea to actually read up on how to use node.

mything.js:

```
var func3 = function() { ... },
    prop = "something";
...
module.exports = {
  func1: function() { ... },
  func2: function() { ... },
  func3: funct3,
  prop: prop,
  ...
};
```

which is identical to:

```
var func3 = function() { ... },
    prop = "something",
    ...
    MyLib = {
      func1: function() { ... },
      func2: function() { ... },
      func3: funct3,
      prop: prop,
      ...
    };
...
module.exports = MyLib;
```

app.js:

```
var mything = require("mything);
```

Comment: Well, I didn't think of that myself, you can be sure of that. I've read it somewhere. Underscore does something very similar but the code is a bit too confusing for me to understand. What it definitely doesn't do is what you wrote here.

Comment: Maybe the name confused you. "Node.js" is not a javascript library. It's the name for a server side engine that lets you write scripts using the JavaScript syntax, using a callback-based event system, with a full standard library including package imports, all formalised as the Node API... it has virtually nothing to do with what you find in client-side libraries that you `<script src=...` include on a page, like underscore, or backbone, or angular, or ember, or whatever else client-side library you're looking at.

Comment: But I'm using Underscore in my node.js project. I can see Underscore's source and it looks like what I described. I require it in my code like I described and it works. The difference is it isn't AS simple as module.exports = this, but it's pretty damn close. It definitely doesn't name each function separately like you did.

Comment: that's because I'm giving you the structure for the code you've shown. If you already have a large library, it's far easier to go `var MyLib = lots of code; module.exports = MyLib;`, and it's exactly the same kind of code, except with the object definition separated from the export. Let me edit my post to show you the equivalence. Underscore does its thing because it looks for whether it's being used in node, and then cloaks the module.exports function to look like what underscore normally uses, see https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L58

Comment: I see. Looks like Underscore does _.someFunction instead of just someFunction and then exports the _ object. Thank you for the patience. The thing is, this WORKED not so long ago but then I changed something and it stopped working.

Comment: Those situations are the worst. Incidentally, I don't know if you -1'd the post, but if you did, could I ask you to undo that? If it wasn't you, I'm not sure why it got downvoted, because it's verifiably correct information... =x

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted, but it could be because of the unnecessary slightly aggressive tone. Everything up to and including '"What gives" is that you didn't read up on how node works' could be dropped without losing anything of importance.

Comment: could be (although that's not what votes are for of course, and it was a response in the same tone as the question =) Thanks @LukaHorvat

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost see [this](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global) link.

Now lets see your code -

```
    var stats = require("./stats");
    //My steps - 

    //First Log
    console.log(stats.func1); // returns undefined
    //Second Log
    console.log(global.func1, global === GLOBAL); // returns [Function], true
```

Take aways from this code -
1. In the browser the global object is `window` object.
2. In node.js it is the `global` object.
3. Defining something **using** `var` in a module will only create a variable with a `module` scope.
4. Defining something **without** the `var` keyword will create a variable in the global scope.

So `func1` and `func2` were defined in the global scope. Passing this to `module.exports` will pass the current  module object only.

hope it helps, happy coding!